# Summing Bernoulli numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

Consider the [Bernoulli numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html) denoted by $B_n$, which are rational numbers.

It is known that the harmonic numbers $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ are not integers once $n>1$.

I am curious about the following:

> **Question:** If $n>0$, will $\sum_{k=0}^nB_k$ ever be an integer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can never be an integer for $n>0$. There is a result by K.G.C. von Staudt and independently by T. Clausen that
$$B_n+\sum_{p\in \mathbb{P}\, ,\, p-1|n}\frac{1}{p}\in \mathbb Z$$

> [1] T. Clausen. Lehrsatz aus einer Abhandlung uber die Bernoullischen Zahlen.
>   Astr. Nachr., 17:351–352, 1840
>
> [2] K. G. C. von Staudt. Beweis eines Lehrsatzes die Bernoulli'schen Zahlen
>   betreffend. J. Reine Angew. Math., 21:372–374, 1840

Using this we see that the integrality of $\sum_{k=0}^n B_k$ is equivalent to the integrality of
$$\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\sum_{p\in \mathbb P \, , \, p-1|k}\frac{1}{p}\right)=\sum_{p\in \mathbb P}\frac{\lfloor\frac{n}{p-1}\rfloor}{p}$$
If $q$ is the largest prime $\le n$ we have $\lfloor \frac{n}{q-1}\rfloor =1$ therefore our expression has $q$-valuation $-1$, so is not an integer.

Answer (score 8):

It is never an integer. By Bertrand postulate there exists a prime $p=2s+1$ between $n/2$ and $n$, it divides the denominator of $B_{p-1}$ and not of other summands in your sum, by von Staudt - Clausen Theorem.